# Problema al ejecutar un Update en Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, update

Amigos tengo un problema para ejecutar un Update a la base de datos para que cuando alguien inicie sesión en el sistema este pueda registrar la fecha y hora. Normalmente funcionaría, pero no sé que estoy haciendo mal. Adjunto el codigo.

'''

```
package pdp;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.sql.*;

import opensoft.database.DBMS;
import opensoft.servlet.*;
import opensoft.utils.Passwd;

import java.security.*;

/** Maneja las conexiones de usuarios al sistema.
    Si el nombre de usuario y password no corresponden despliega mensaje.
    En caso contrario despliega página almacenada en la sesion como login.target,
    o bien página de bienvenida.
 */
public class LoginHandler extends PDPServlet {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginHandler.class);

    /** Construye pagina de conexion
     */
    protected void buildPage(Connection con, HttpServletRequest req,
                            HttpServletResponse res, PrintWriter out)
    throws SQLException, IOException, ExpiredSessionException, BuildPageException, UserException {

        logger.info("-- LoginHandler --");

        //System.out.println("========================AQUI====================");
        // Recupera user's name y password
        String name   = req.getParameter("name");
        String passwd = req.getParameter("passwd");

        logger.info("-- name:   "+name+" --");
        logger.info("-- passwd: "+passwd+" --");

        // Crea un objeto para enviar SQL
        Statement stmt;
        try{
             stmt = con.createStatement();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            throw new UserException("Lo sentimos, en este momento hay muchos usuarios conectados. <BR>" +
                                    "Por favor espere.");
        }

        // Chequea que sean validos
        if (!allowUser(name, passwd, stmt)) {

        // Descomentar para crear primer usuario
        //if (false){

            // Si no es valido
            throw new UserException("Su nombre de usuario y/o contraseña no son válidos.");
        }
        else{
            // Si es válido, marca sesión como autentificada y pasa a la siguiente página
            try{

                // Hace una marca en la sesion del usuario
                HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
                session.setAttribute("logon.isDone", name); 

                // Intenta redireccionar a la pagina que este guardada en su sesion
                String target = (String) session.getAttribute("login.target");
                if (target != null){
                    session.removeAttribute("login.target");
                    res.sendRedirect(target);
                    return;
                }
                fechaIngreso(name, stmt);
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e){
                ShowError("No se pudo recuperar sesión", e, out);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                ShowError(e, out);
            }

            try{

                // Si no ha podido redireccionar, envia a pagina bienvenida
                String scheme     = req.getScheme();
                String serverName = req.getServerName();
        if (req.getServerPort() != 80)
          serverName = req.getServerName() + ":" + req.getServerPort();
                res.sendRedirect(scheme + "://" + serverName + "/" + is_welcomeSecurePage);

            }
            catch(NullPointerException e){
                ShowError("Página de bienvenida está nula", e, out);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                ShowError(e, out);
            }
        }
    }

    /** Método que verifica en la BD si el usuario está registrado.
     */
    private boolean allowUser(String user, String passwd, Statement stmt) {

        // Declara variables locales
        ResultSet rs  = null;
        String    sql = null;
        String    rs_pass;
        boolean   ret = false;

        // Obtiene password encriptado
        String enc_passwd;
        try {
            Passwd pw = new Passwd( passwd );
            enc_passwd = pw.getPasswd();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            return ret;
        }

        // Declara SQL
        sql = "select * from usuario " +
              "where login = " + "'" + user + "'"; // and password='"+enc_passwd+"'";
    //System.out.println(sql);
        try{
            // ejecuta instrucción en SQL
            rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );

            // recupera primera fila de la respuesta
            rs.next();
            rs_pass = rs.getString("password");
            //System.out.println(enc_passwd+"______"+rs_pass);
            // verifica password
            if (!rs.wasNull()) ret = ( rs_pass.equals( enc_passwd ) );
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            // Ignora y mantiene valor false para retornar
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            // Ignora y mantiene valor false para retornar
        }
        finally {
            try{
                stmt.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){ }
            catch (NullPointerException ignored){}
        }

        // Retorna
        return ret;

    }


    private boolean fechaIngreso(String login, Statement stmt) throws SQLException{

        String sql = null;
        boolean   ret = false;

        sql = "UPDATE USUARIO SET FECHAINSCRIPCION = SYSDATE where LOGIN = '" + login + "';";

        try{
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            stmt.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

'''

El método que cree se llama **fechaIngreso()** y me guíe por otro metodo que existía en la clase y que solo cambie a update.
Agrego el error que arroja.

'''

```
java.sql.SQLException: Sentencia cerrada
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java)
    at pdp.LoginHandler.fechaIngreso(LoginHandler.java:167)
    at pdp.LoginHandler.buildPage(LoginHandler.java:76)
    at opensoft.servlet.DBServlet.doGet(DBServlet.java:157)
    at opensoft.servlet.DBServlet.doPost(DBServlet.java:204)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:184)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:972)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:206)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:833)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:732)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:619)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:688)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)
'''
```

Les agradecería si me pueden ayudar a entender que esta ocurriendo, ya que le he dedicado varias horas a solucionar y aun no lo logro.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no falta un open antes de ejecutar el query?

Comment: at pdp.LoginHandler.buildPage(LoginHandler.java:76) ¿Cual es tu línea 76?

Comment: at pdp.LoginHandler.fechaIngreso(LoginHandler.java:167) ¿Cual es tu línea 167?

Comment: Jesus la linea 76 es    ** fechaIngreso(name, stmt);**    y la linea 167  
     **stmt.executeUpdate(sql);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La excepción lo indica muy claramente, en el método allowUser(), estás cerrando tu statement en el bloque finally{} (que se ejecuta siempre), pero luego lo quieres usar de nuevo en el método fechaIngreso(). 
Así que no lo cierres, o bien crea otro para tu segundo método.

Comment: Alex.Muchas gracias coloque otro statement en el metodo fechaIngreso() y funciono sin problemas.

Comment: Por nada, recuerda entonces poner la respuesta como correcta, para que le sirva a alguien más.